# putExtra data not passing between activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a query. I am designing a widget. I have 2 apps in it. I am able to pass intents to one of the apps. But i am facing problem when i try to click FB, intents doesn't work. I get error in passing the data from 1 activity to an other. Data not getting passed from 1 activity to another.

Code class first:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String show = i.getStringExtra("show"); 
if(show.equals("facebook"))
{
 viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
 mListView.setAdapter(mFacebookAdapter);
 currentView = 0;
}
else if(show.equals("twitter"))
{
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
mListView.setAdapter(mTwitterAdapter);
currentView = 1 ;  
}
```

Class second:

```
Intent facebook = new Intent(context, SocialList.class);
facebook.putExtra("show", "facebook");
PendingIntent pendingfb = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, facebook, 0);
```

I need to pass the value from one class to another. In second class i need to get the show value as "facebook" from class first. How can i do that. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code i am using.

Inserting Data:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("profileId", userId);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieving Data:

```
    profileId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("profileId");
```

Comment: Is that possible to put data in the retrieving side ?